# Firebase storage - Limit of simultaneous file uploads with sdk

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

[Firebase Storage SDK Documentation for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) explains how to manage the whole cycle to upload files and resume uploads in Android. However it does not explain or define if there is a limit of simultaneous files that can be uploaded at the same time and obviously it also doesn't tell if you can configure that limit within the SDK.

So the cuestion is, is there a limit of how many simoultaneous file uploads per device can you perform with Firebase storage sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can kick off any number of uploads with the SDK (up to some reasonably large maximum), and the SDK will manage their transfers to the storage bucket.  It should be considered an implementation detail as to how many actually occur at the exact same time, but they will all eventually complete or fail.  The SDK reserves the right to decide the best strategy at any given moment.

Comment: So it means that if I want to implement file limit upload I have to manage it before passing files to firebase sdk to upload right? And then monitor onFailure or onComplete calls to pass more files or retry failed ones